# Joomla for Business Intelligence reports sharing across enterprise

Tags: joomla, business-intelligence, enterprise, sharing

We are looking at various options for common hub where we would wish to publish common business intelligence reports for sharing and providing easier access for information available along with metadata. We do have Microstrategy and Tableu as our enterprise reporting tools but lacking metadata linking to those reports. So we wish to have that link provided through a common hub area where users can explore and understand various information areas themselves to ultimately make it enterprise wide information repository rather than just a reporting application.

We are looking at several other options along with joomla. We understand that joomla is majorly a content management system for websites. But we wish to know your opinion on usage of joomla with probably customized admin console for sharing reports and linking. We currently do not know if it is right way to use so. If any of your organizations follow any easier approach for solving the issue, please suggest us the same. Also if possible, please provide us links on similar use cases along with any examples of customizing joomla admin console.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

I'd use GroupJive the manage communication between groups of users. Groupjive has a wall where links can be posted, is forum (kunena) integrated and has a feature to upload documents.

The access rights for each group is configurable on groupjive, so you can restrict access to some information to some users and define moderators.

Hope it helps!

http://www.joomlapolis.com/cb-solutions/groupjive

Answer (score 1):

If using Joomla .. you could try to build described functionality using ZOO, a flexible and powerful content application builder to manage your content  http://www.yootheme.com/zoo